# Do Dynamixel Servos give position feedback in velocity control mode?

Tags: hardware, dynamixel, servo, dynamixel-controller, dynamixel-motor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some of these servos have as high as 4096 positions/revolution accuracy (0.088°). So I think if I command it to go to a particular position, say 100°, the actual position will be between 100.088° and 99.912.

But if the servo is in velocity control mode (continuous rotation) will I be able to get information on the position at some instance in time with the same +/- 0.088°? This is because I have to synchronize the positions with the frames published by a camera.

I would deeply appreciate it if someone with experience with these high-end servos can share their thoughts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300076/do-dynamixel-servos-give-position-feedback-in-velocity-control-mode?/) by [jelly_legs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33941/jelly_legs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course, you can get present position of Dynamixels through `present_position` register.
I recommend to use [DynamixelSDK](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/DynamixelSDK) or [Dynamixel-workbench](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/dynamixel-workbench) packages.

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/x/xm430-w210/#present-position

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1